# logging from python to robot framework not working for subprocess.call

Tags: python, logging, robotframework

I have a function called Log that writes a log string to the robot framework log files.
If I call this function from within A.py where its defined , it logs into the output.html as expected. But if i call this function from another python function init.py which in turn is invoked from A.py itself using subprocess.call, It does not log into output.html. It simply ignores it.
**A.py:**

```
def Log( logString,typeOfLog):
        ts = time.time()
        st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print(st)
        if typeOfLog=="INFO":
                logger.console(st + '  ' + logString)
                logger.info(logString)
        elif typeOfLog=="DEBUG":
                logger.console(st + '  ' + logString)
                logger.debug(logString)
        elif typeOfLog=="WARN":
                logger.console(st + '  ' + logString)
                logger.warn(logString)
        elif typeOfLog=="ERROR":
                logger.console(st + '  ' + logString)
                logger.error(st + '  ' + logString)
        elif typeOfLog=="":
                logger.console(logString)
                logger.trace(logString)
.
.
.
.
def Test():
        Log("My debug statement in DEPLOY.PY","INFO")----->gets logged to output.html
        ret = subprocess.call("python init.py", shell=True)
        .
        .
        .
```

**Code for init.py:**

```
from A import Log
from robot.api import logger
def initfunc1():
        Log("Something","INFO")------>this does not get logged to output.html

initfunc1()
```

IF someone can explain why this is happening and how to make the calls to Log function from init.py also to log into output.html as expected, it would be of great help to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `logger`?

Comment: I have imported it from robot.api so that i can log to the robot framework console from python..

Comment: What is `logger` in A? The same? Where are you telling it to output to `output.html`

Comment: yes its the same in A.py. There is a package called robot.api that exposes the APIs of robot framework. So I am using the logger module from that package to log to robot framework from my python code. I dont explicitly mention to log into output.html anywhere. But when i run the robot script(that in turn invokes A.py's Test()), It automatically creates output.html which contains the logs logged using logger.info etc..

Comment: I would assume the problem is that when you use `subprocess`, the two python instances are completely separated, meaning that only one of them can write to `output.html` at the same time. I however aren't versed in the framework and can't help you. If possible, it might be better to not use subprocess at all.

Answer (score 0):

The process started with `subprocess.call` does not have access to the Robot Frameworks (RF) execution context that would be required for it to be able to write log messages into the RF output files (output.xml, log.html, ...). In this case, as the process is unable to find the context, the `robot.api.logger` will log the messages with python logging module, see [logger docs](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/_modules/robot/api/logger.html) for details.

In order to get output from the subprocess to the robot logs, you could use `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.call` to capture the output of the child process and log this captured output to the RF output. See also the RF [Process library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html) for another way to execute processes from RF.